# How to get an id of an added object from an Activity(VIEW) in a database(MODEL) through VIEWMODEL | Android, MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

- I have a ShoppingList App that is built on **MVVM architecture Android**.
- I did not make it, but I followed a tutorial on Youtube.
- This is the image of the app(1/2) where the shopping list is shown. The bottom right side is a button for adding new elements of the list.

[image]

- This is the second view(2/2) where the dialog appears to enter a name of our element and amount of it. Here we have cancel button and **add button**.

[image]

The problem is when I click the **ADD button** on the Dialog Box I do not know how to get an ID of this added item to the recycler view on my VIEW and to make it appear via the TOAST command on my main Activity.

The question is - **How to get an ID of a new added element to my shopping list and show it on my MainActivity(ShoppingActivity) VIEW *when I click the ADD button*?**

If you need additional information ask me out immediately! I will provide you anything you need.

Code is provided here:

**ShoppingActivity(View)**

```
class ShoppingActivity : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {
override val kodein by kodein()
private val factory: ShoppingViewModelFactory by instance()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping)

    // View Model is being created out of other classes to set changes to View

    val viewModel =  ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ShoppingViewModel::class.java)

    // Adapters and Recycler View

    val adapter = ShoppingItemAdapter(listOf(), viewModel)
    rvShoppingItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvShoppingItems.adapter = adapter


    // ViewModel makes changes to the Activity

    viewModel.getAllShoppingItems().observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.items = it
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        AddShoppingItemDialog(this ,
            object: AddDialogListener{
                override fun onAddButtonClicked(item: ShoppingItem) {
                    viewModel.upsert(item)
                    showToast(viewModel.getID(item).toString().toInt())

                }
            }).show()
    }

}

fun showToast(id: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(this@ShoppingActivity, "ID записи: $id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}}
```

**ShoppingViewModel(ViewModel)**

```
class ShoppingViewModel(private val repository: ShoppingRepository): ViewModel() {

fun upsert(item: ShoppingItem) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    repository.upsert(item)
}

fun delete(item: ShoppingItem) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    repository.delete( item)
}

fun getID(item: ShoppingItem) = repository.getID(item)


fun getAllShoppingItems() = repository.getAllShoppingItems()

}
```

AddShoppingItemDialog(the logic of showing Dialog info)

```
class AddShoppingItemDialog(context: Context, var addDialogListener: AddDialogListener): AppCompatDialog(context)  {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_shopping_item)

    tvAdd.setOnClickListener {
        val name = etName.text.toString()
        val amount = etAmount.text.toString()

        if(name.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter the name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        if(amount.isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter the amount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        val item = ShoppingItem(name, amount.toInt())

        // We need to

        addDialogListener.onAddButtonClicked(item)
        dismiss()
    }

    tvCancel.setOnClickListener {
        cancel()
    }
}}
```

**Repository**

```
class ShoppingRepository(private val db: ShoppingDatabase) {

suspend fun upsert(item: ShoppingItem) = db.getShoppingDao().upsert(item)
suspend fun delete(item: ShoppingItem) = db.getShoppingDao().delete(item)
fun getID(item: ShoppingItem) = db.getShoppingDao().getID(item)

fun getAllShoppingItems() = db.getShoppingDao().getAllShoppingItems()}
```

**ShoppingDAO**

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun upsert(item: ShoppingItem) : Long

@Delete
suspend fun delete(item: ShoppingItem)

@Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_items WHERE id = $CURRENT_POSITION")
fun getID(item: ShoppingItem): LiveData<Int>

@Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_items")
fun getAllShoppingItems(): LiveData<List<ShoppingItem>>
}
```

**ShoppingItem**

```
const val CURRENT_POSITION = 0

@Entity(tableName = "shopping_items")

data class ShoppingItem(


@ColumnInfo(name = "item_name")
var name: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "item_amount")
var amount: Int
) {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Int? = CURRENT_POSITION


}
```

**AddDialogListener**

```
interface AddDialogListener {

fun onAddButtonClicked(item: ShoppingItem)
```

}

**App View with added items**

[image]

Comment: Is there any item inside your db initially?

Comment: No, if only I add something firstly via the app UI

Comment: I added a AddDialogListener  interface code to the end of this post. 

Also, AddShoppingItemDialog is not an interface, but we AddDialogListener Interface as a parameter to our AddShoppingItemDialog

Comment: Leo, if you are asking about the id then it is added to the db, but I do not know how to retrieve the id from the database to it on ShoppingActivity in toast once an item is loaded

Comment: Leo, the app shows all the items added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since insert/upsert operations on Database are suspend functions, observe returned id in view model

In `ShoppingViewModel`

```
private var _itemId : Long = MutableLiveData<Long>()
val itemId : LiveData<Long>
get() = _itemId

fun upsert(item: ShoppingItem) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val id = repository.upsert(item)
    _itemId.postValue(id)
}
```

In `ShoppingActivity`,

```
viewModel.itemId.observe(this, Observer {id ->
    showToast(id)

})
```

Please let me know if you need to know more details.

Comment: Glad I could help!:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SingleLiveEvent to observe the value only once.
Add this SingleLiveEvent class

```
/**
 * A lifecycle-aware observable that sends only new updates after subscription, used for events like
 * navigation and Snackbar messages.
 *
 *
 * This avoids a common problem with events: on configuration change (like rotation) an update
 * can be emitted if the observer is active. This LiveData only calls the observable if there's an
 * explicit call to setValue() or call().
 *
 *
 * Note that only one observer is going to be notified of changes.
 */
class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val mPending = AtomicBoolean(false)

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {

        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
        }

        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->
            if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        })
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(t: T?) {
        mPending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }

    /**
     * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
     */
    @MainThread
    fun call() {
        value = null
    }

    companion object {

        private val TAG = "SingleLiveEvent"
    }
}
```

In ShoppingViewModel

Replace this

```
private var _itemId : Long = MutableLiveData<Long>()
val itemId : LiveData<Long>
get() = _itemId
```

with

```
private var _itemId : Long = SingleLiveEvent<Long>()
val itemId : LiveData<Long>
get() = _itemId
```

You can use Event wrapper when there are more than one observer.
For more details:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150